# How to organize large number of JS files in index.html file in angularjs application

Tags: angularjs

I am working on angular js application where I have huge number of JS files regarding controllers,services,directives,plugins,thirdparty modules which I have included in single index.html file.

But the problem is even if any one of the module which any one of my team member is working gets error the whole site goes down making others stop there work.

Is there any solution to this?